# symfony 1.4: redeclared getter makes doctrine:data-load task fail silently

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, fixtures, doctrine-1.2

Here is my part of my schema:

```
sfGuardUser:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    email_address:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
      unique: true
    algorithm:
      type: string(128)
      default: sha1
      notnull: true
    salt: string(128)
    password: string(128)
    balance: 
      type: decimal(14)
      scale: 4
      default: 0
    guarantee:
      type: decimal(14)
      scale: 4
      default: 0
    is_active:
      type: boolean
      default: 1
    is_super_admin:
      type: boolean
      default: false
    last_login:
      type: timestamp
```

Here is fixture data:

```
sfGuardUser:
  User_admin_1:
    email_address:  admin@company.com
    password:       admin
    balance:        10000
    is_super_admin: true
```

Here is getter which make it fail

```
class sfGuardUser extends PluginsfGuardUser
{
  ... 

  public function getBalance()
  {
    return (parent::getBalance() - $this->getGuarantee());
  }
}
```

If I remove `parent::getBalance()` everything works fine. What's trouble with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to call `$this->get('balance')` or `$this->_get('balance')` to get a record from Doctrine. These functions retrieve the value in the doctrine model.